# PDF write error using PDF Clown

Tags: pdf, pdfclown

I have a PDF file which i am reading using PDF Clown and then adding some annotations to it. After that i am trying to serialize the file to disk using Save method of org.pdfclown.files.File. In doing so i am getting following error

> An exception happened while running the sample:
>   org.pdfclown.util.parsers.PostScriptParseException: Unknown type beginning: 'False'
>      at org.pdfclown.tokens.BaseParser.ParsePdfObject() in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\tokens\BaseParser.cs:line 149
>      at org.pdfclown.tokens.FileParser.ParsePdfObject() in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\tokens\FileParser.cs:line 150
>      at org.pdfclown.tokens.FileParser.ParsePdfObject(XRefEntry xrefEntry) in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\tokens\FileParser.cs:line 221
>      at org.pdfclown.objects.PdfIndirectObject.get_DataObject() in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\objects\PdfIndirectObject.cs:line 275
>      at org.pdfclown.objects.PdfIndirectObject.WriteTo(IOutputStream stream, File context) in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\objects\PdfIndirectObject.cs:line 248
>      at org.pdfclown.tokens.PlainWriter.WriteStandard() in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\tokens\PlainWriter.cs:line 205
>      at org.pdfclown.tokens.Writer.Write(SerializationModeEnum mode) in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\tokens\Writer.cs:line 132
>      at org.pdfclown.files.File.Save(IOutputStream stream, SerializationModeEnum mode) in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\files\File.cs:line 315
>      at org.pdfclown.files.File.Save(String path, SerializationModeEnum mode) in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.lib\src\org\pdfclown\files\File.cs:line 272
>      at org.pdfclown.samples.cli.HelloWorldSample.UzairTestFunc() in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.samples.cli\src\org\pdfclown\samples\cli\HelloWorldSample.cs:line 40
>      at org.pdfclown.samples.cli.HelloWorldSample.Run() in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.samples.cli\src\org\pdfclown\samples\cli\HelloWorldSample.cs:line 20
>      at org.pdfclown.samples.cli.SampleLoader.Run(String inputPath, String outputPath) in d:\eProof\testProjects\pdf_clown_svn\dotNET\pdfclown.samples.cli\src\org\pdfclown\samples\cli\SampleLoader.cs:line 123

Now i cant share the PDF here, but i see that it is not able to handle the following object in the PDF 
...
96 0 obj
False
endobj
...

Any ideas how to resolve this in PDF Clown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> 96 0 obj
> False
> endobj
> ```

This object is invalid, boolean values are all lowercase:

> #### 7.3.2 Boolean objects
>
> *Boolean objects* represent the logical values of true and false. They appear in PDF files using the keywords **true** and **false**.

*(both ISO 32000-1 and ISO 32000-2)*

To repair your PDF, therefore, please replace `False` by `false`.

Comment: but Adobe Reader is able to open that PDF perfectly

Comment: Adobe Reader ignores many errors in PDFs. This does not make the erroneous PDFs valid.